# How to make a button that does the same that another button was doing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an authentication site, but I want to make log in buttons to many languages, so I want to make a button that does the same that another was doing.

This is the button that I want to clone

```
firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
```

I'm expecting that someone tell me how can I make this button

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

/* Shared */

.loginBtn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 13em;  - apply for fixed size */
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0 15px 0 46px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.loginBtn:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 100%;
}

.loginBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.loginBtn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* Google */

.loginBtn--google {
  /*font-family: "Roboto", Roboto, arial, sans-serif;*/
  background: #DD4B39;
}

.loginBtn--google:before {
  border-right: #BB3F30 1px solid;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/icon_google.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}

.loginBtn--google:hover,
.loginBtn--google:focus {
  background: #E74B37;
}
```

```html
<button class="loginBtn loginBtn--google">Login with Google</button>
```

Comment: And you want to put a lot of button on your login page? I think what you looking for is localization (l10n)

Comment: I just want to put a login button and a facebook button!

Comment: Tbh: It is utterly unclear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: I just want to make a  button that does the same function that other button is doing!

Comment: What other button?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think would be easier to do a translator with [JSON](https://www.json.org/) than to make so many buttons or elements. Like that:

```js
// Foreach language, a Json object
// Foreach node element, a key in Json (I reccomend to use it ID)
var json = [
  {
    "lang" : "en",
    "googleBtn" : "Login with Google"
  },
  {
    "lang" : "pt",
    "googleBtn" : "Logar com Google"
  },
  {
    "lang" : "es",
    "googleBtn" : "Logar con Google"
  }
]

window.onload = function(){
  var btn = document.getElementById("googleBtn");
  var lang = document.getElementById("lang");
  
  // When change the language
  lang.onchange = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
      if (json[i].lang == lang.value){
        content = json[i]; // Catch what language it is
      }
    }
    btn.innerHTML = content.googleBtn;  // Rewrite texts
  };
};
```

```css
/* I just used your code here */

.loginBtn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 13em;  - apply for fixed size */
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0 15px 0 46px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.loginBtn:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 100%;
}

.loginBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.loginBtn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* Google */

.loginBtn--google {
  /*font-family: "Roboto", Roboto, arial, sans-serif;*/
  background: #DD4B39;
}

.loginBtn--google:before {
  border-right: #BB3F30 1px solid;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/icon_google.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}

.loginBtn--google:hover,
.loginBtn--google:focus {
  background: #E74B37;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="lang">
    <option value="en" selected>English</option>
    <option value="pt">Português</option>
    <option value="es">Español</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button class="loginBtn loginBtn--google" id="googleBtn">Login with Google</button>
```

Comment: I would suggest making the language code as the keys of an object instead or including them at the same level as the translations in an array. It makes lookup easier. So for instance, `localizationDictionary = { en: { googleButton: 'Login with Google'}, es: { googleButton: 'Logar con Google'}}` etc. Then you don't need the loop to find the right translation, you can just look up `localizationDictionary[lang.value]` and you have all the translations for the proper language already :)

Comment: Oh, thanks, I don't knew that function, I'll update my code just when I come at home xD

Comment: Look, in my code there is a button, I just want to add code that will make the button do the same thing of this one```firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID```